# Spearman's - monotonic?

Tags: spss

Deas,

One assumption for Spearman's correlation is that data have to be monotonic .. I tried to do scatterplot in spss, but I get the following graph that I couldn't decide if it is monotonic .. What is the solution please ? Note: my data are ordinal variables.

[image: Scatterplot gragh]

Comment: You can't see *anything* here because you're just plotting multiple points on top of each other. Each give it as a table instead, or jitter the points so they can all be seen. Until you fix your question, nobody can say much.

Comment: There is option to jitter points or to show their counts under a single dot by means of the size of the marker.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the two variables need at least to be ordinal scaled. There is no assumption that there is a monotone association between the variables. In fact, Spearman's rank correlation is measuring exactly how monotone the association is. A value of zero means no monotone association, while a value close to one (or -1) means that large values in one variable clearly tend to large (or small) values in the other variable.

Your picture is not very informative. Try to highlight the sample size behind each combination.